# Why is RCC PLL not enabled on STM32G474RE

Tags: c, stm32

I am trying to configure the RCC clock of a STM32G474RE board with PLL using HSI16 as clock source and PLLM = 1, PLLN = 10, AHB = 1, APB1 = 1 and APB2 = 4 as the configuration. However when I run the code the PLLRDY flag is never set and I'm stuck in the infinite loop.

```
#include "main.h"

void SytemClockConfig(void){
    /*Enable HSI16*/
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSION;
    while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY)){}
    
    /*Configure PWR and FLASH*/
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_PWREN;
    PWR->CR1 |= (0x01 & PWR_CR1_VOS_Msk);
    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_2WS | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN;
        
    /*Configure AHB and APB*/
    RCC->CFGR |= (0x00 & RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Msk);
    RCC->CFGR |= (0x00 & RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_Msk);
    RCC->CFGR |= (0x05 & RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_Msk);
        
    /*Config PLL*/
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x02 & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_Msk);
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x00 & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Msk);
    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Msk);
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x0A & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Msk);
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x01 & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLREN_Msk);
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0x00 & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_Msk);

        
    /*Enable PLL*/
    RCC->CR |= (0x01 & RCC_CR_PLLON);
    while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY)){}
        
    RCC->CFGR |= (0x05 & RCC_CFGR_SW_Msk);
    while((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != (0x03 & RCC_CFGR_SWS_Msk)){}
} 

int main(void){
    SytemClockConfig();
    
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply do not write the values you think you write. You need to learn how binary logical operations work. Basically, almost all operations are wrong. I will give you only some examples.

- `RCC->CR |= (0x01 & RCC_CR_PLLON);` this operation does nothin'. PLLON bit is at position 24. You binary AND `1` and `1 << 24`. The result is `0`. Then you binary OR it to the RCC -> CR register. This operation does nothing. ***You need to `RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;`***
- `RCC->CFGR |= (0x00 & RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Msk);` it is the same as `RCC->CFGR |= 0`; (It **does not** zero HPRE bits!!!)

And many many more (almost all of them).

I would suggest to practice binary logic operations before attempting any bare metal programming.

If you want to:

- set bit at position `n` - `VAL |= (1U << n)`
- reset bit at the position `n` - `VAL &= ~(1 << n)`
- toggle bit at the position `n` - `VAL ^= (1 << n)`

If you want to put value `5` into `PPRE2` bits in the register

```
uint32_t tmp = RCC->CFGR;
tmp &= ~RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_Msk;
tmp |= 5UL << RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_Pos
RCC->CFGR = tmp;
```

I would suggest using temporary variables and **assign** value to the register.